# Zinnia growing tall and look skinny

Tags: flowers, sunlight, zinnia

I planted zinnia seed like 1 - 1.5mo ago and now it's quite tall, 10" or so
The leaves look rather small. And one is showing flowering.

Is this normal? Is it lacking sun? Because I live in Pacific Northwest.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never had Zinnias, but the plant in the picture looks like a healthy plant. If a plant doesn't get enough (direct) sunlight it looks skinny and leggy which is here not the case. Usually these leggy plants can't even stand up straight anymore.

On google I found a picture [here](https://www.dreamstime.com/girls-hands-holding-plant-zinnia-flower-seedling-ready-to-transplant-garden-zinnia-flower-seedling-image139291259) with more or less the same height and stem thickness. So I think they will be fine!